# Lex - double quotation mark inside string

Tags: regex, string, lex

I have lex grammar that contains rules for double quotes string:

```
...
%x DOUBLEQUOTE
...
%%
"\""                { yylval->string = NULL; BEGIN(DOUBLEQUOTE); }
<DOUBLEQUOTE> {
    "\n"            {
                        /* reset column counter on new line */
                        PARSER->linepos = 0;
                        (PARSER->linenum)++;
                        expr_parser_append_string(PARSER, &(yylval->string), yytext);
                    }
    [^\"\n]+        { expr_parser_append_string(PARSER, &(yylval->string), yytext); }
    "\\\""          { expr_parser_append_string(PARSER, &(yylval->string), yytext); }
    "\""            {
                        BEGIN(INITIAL);
                        if ( yylval->string != NULL )
                            string_unescape_c(yylval->string);
                        return ( TOKEN_STRING );
                    }
}
```

Somehow the escape sequence **\"** is matched only at beginning of a string. If the **\"** appears latter in a string it looks like the characters **\** and **"** are matched separately.

For instance:

1. Passes: `"\"    "`
2. Fails:  `" \"   "`
3. Fails:  `"This is string example: \"a string inside of string\""`

Why the escape sequence **\"** is not matched by the rule `"\\\""` when appears latter in a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the backslash is not the first character in the quoted string, then the backslash will be matched at the end of some token. For example:

```
 "abc\"def"
  ^^^^       First token, longest match of [^"\n]+
      ^      Terminates quoted string
```

So you need to exclude backslashes as well. But once you do that, you need to provide a pattern which does match backslash escapes, not just backslash-escaped quotes. So I'd suggest:

```
<DOUBLEQUOTE>{
  \\?\n              { /* Handle newline */ }
  ([^"\\\n]|\\.)+    { expr_parser_append_string(PARSER,
                                                 &yylval->string,
                                                 yytext); }
  \"                 { BEGIN(INITIAL); ... }
}
```

Note: I added an optional backslash to the beginning of the first pattern, in order to handle the case where the backslash immediately precedes a newline character. The `.` in the second pattern (`\\.`) will not match a newline so otherwise backslash-newline wouldn't be recognized at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
[^\"\n]+        { expr_parser_append_string(PARSER, &(yylval->string), yytext); }
```

In addition to quotes and newlines, this rule should also exclude backslashes. Or it should be moved so it's last in the list.